# onTap changes color of all Cards, not just the one that was tapped

Tags: flutter

I'm displaying a product list (using ListView.builder) and I am trying to make it so that the color of the Card that wraps the ListTile changes when the ListTile is tapped. My code is below.

What happens instead is...when I click on one of the Cards, the entire screen changes color (blue in this case) -- the color of ALL the Cards is changed.

**How can I ensure the color of the Card I tapped on is changed, not all the Cards?**

```
class MyHomepage extends StatefulWidget {

  final List<Product> productList;
  const MyHomepage({Key key, this.productList}): super(key: key);

  @override
  MyHomepageState createState() => MyHomepageState();
}


class MyHomepageState extends State<MyHomepage> {
  bool isSelected = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: widget.productList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {

        return new Card(
            color: isSelected ? Colors.lightBlueAccent : Colors.transparent,
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text('${widget.productList[index].name}'),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  isSelected = !isSelected;
                });
              },
            )
        );
      },
    );
  } // build
} // MyHomepageState
```

Comment: You can use a List<bool> to track which one got tapped, so that the color can be changed for the particular card.

Comment: `setState(() {widget.productList[index].isSelected = !widget.productList[index].isSelected;});`

Comment: Thanks. That worked.

Comment: @pskink It took me a while to see what you were getting at. Now I see, the selected state is (or should be) stored in the Product class, not in MyHomepageState class. Thanks, that makes sense.

Comment: good, your welcome